# How to use the ^DG command send image to a zebra printer in java?

Tags: java, image, zebra-printers, zpl

Is anyone know how to convert a image(such as *.bmp files) to HEX string in java,so the HEX string can used in the ^DG command(one of command in zpl).thanks!

Comment: Zebra printers are not exactly mainstream technology. You'd better include the hex format requirements in your question.

Comment: Here is the description(you can see the ^DG command) about hex format in the [zpl maual document](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6755).

Comment: I wrote an online converter right here http://www.jcgonzalez.com/zpl-ascii-hex-representation-image-generator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not easy. You have to convert the image to 1-bit per pixel b/w, and then calculate the size including the bytes per row, and then properly form up the parameters of the `~DG` command to store it.

Or...

Zebra provides an API to convert images to GRFs (Zebra internal image type).  There are a bunch of developer demos in the package, including a demo on how to print/store an image as a GRF on your printer

[Zebra Link-OS SDK download](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much!Can give a demo about method 1?

Answer (score 4):

I have written an java example that can do that. 
You can also create ascii hex code or compressed ZPL code and select blackness percentage to improve accuracy.

Change the parameters in the main method accordingly. For a more extensive explanation  [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/java-image-to-zpl-example)

*To test the result without printing here [enter](http://labelary.com/viewer.html)

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class ZPLConveter {
    private int blackLimit = 380;
    private int total;
    private int widthBytes;
    private boolean compressHex = false;
    private static Map<Integer, String> mapCode = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    {
        mapCode.put(1, "G");
        mapCode.put(2, "H");
        mapCode.put(3, "I");
        mapCode.put(4, "J");
        mapCode.put(5, "K");
        mapCode.put(6, "L");
        mapCode.put(7, "M");
        mapCode.put(8, "N");
        mapCode.put(9, "O");
        mapCode.put(10, "P");
        mapCode.put(11, "Q");
        mapCode.put(12, "R");
        mapCode.put(13, "S");
        mapCode.put(14, "T");
        mapCode.put(15, "U");
        mapCode.put(16, "V");
        mapCode.put(17, "W");
        mapCode.put(18, "X");
        mapCode.put(19, "Y");
        mapCode.put(20, "g");
        mapCode.put(40, "h");
        mapCode.put(60, "i");
        mapCode.put(80, "j");
        mapCode.put(100, "k");
        mapCode.put(120, "l");
        mapCode.put(140, "m");
        mapCode.put(160, "n");
        mapCode.put(180, "o");
        mapCode.put(200, "p");
        mapCode.put(220, "q");
        mapCode.put(240, "r");
        mapCode.put(260, "s");
        mapCode.put(280, "t");
        mapCode.put(300, "u");
        mapCode.put(320, "v");
        mapCode.put(340, "w");
        mapCode.put(360, "x");
        mapCode.put(380, "y");        
        mapCode.put(400, "z");            
    }
    public String convertfromImg(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        String body = createBody(image);
        if(compressHex)
           body = encodeHexAscii(body);
        return headDoc() + body + footDoc();        
    }
    private String createBody(BufferedImage orginalImage) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Graphics2D graphics = orginalImage.createGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(orginalImage, 0, 0, null);
        int height = orginalImage.getHeight();
        int width = orginalImage.getWidth();
        int rgb, red, green, blue, index=0;        
        char auxBinaryChar[] =  {'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
        widthBytes = width/8;
        if(width%8>0){
            widthBytes= (((int)(width/8))+1);
        } else {
            widthBytes= width/8;
        }
        this.total = widthBytes*height;
        for (int h = 0; h<height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w<width; w++)
            {
                rgb = orginalImage.getRGB(w, h);
                red = (rgb >> 16 ) & 0x000000FF;
                green = (rgb >> 8 ) & 0x000000FF;
                blue = (rgb) & 0x000000FF;
                char auxChar = '1';
                int totalColor = red + green + blue;
                if(totalColor>blackLimit){
                    auxChar = '0';
                }
                auxBinaryChar[index] = auxChar;
                index++;
                if(index==8 || w==(width-1)){
                    sb.append(fourByteBinary(new String(auxBinaryChar)));
                    auxBinaryChar =  new char[]{'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'};
                    index=0;
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private String fourByteBinary(String binaryStr){
        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binaryStr,2);
        if (decimal>15){
            return Integer.toString(decimal,16).toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return "0" + Integer.toString(decimal,16).toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    private String encodeHexAscii(String code){
        int maxlinea =  widthBytes * 2;        
        StringBuffer sbCode = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sbLinea = new StringBuffer();
        String previousLine = null;
        int counter = 1;
        char aux = code.charAt(0);
        boolean firstChar = false; 
        for(int i = 1; i< code.length(); i++ ){
            if(firstChar){
                aux = code.charAt(i);
                firstChar = false;
                continue;
            }
            if(code.charAt(i)=='\n'){
                if(counter>=maxlinea && aux=='0'){
                    sbLinea.append(",");
                } else     if(counter>=maxlinea && aux=='F'){
                    sbLinea.append("!");
                } else if (counter>20){
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int resto20 = (counter%20);
                    sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(multi20));
                    if(resto20!=0){
                        sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(resto20) + aux);    
                    } else {
                        sbLinea.append(aux);    
                    }
                } else {
                    sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(counter) + aux);
                    if(mapCode.get(counter)==null){
                    }
                }
                counter = 1;
                firstChar = true;
                if(sbLinea.toString().equals(previousLine)){
                    sbCode.append(":");
                } else {
                    sbCode.append(sbLinea.toString());
                }                
                previousLine = sbLinea.toString();
                sbLinea.setLength(0);
                continue;
            }
            if(aux == code.charAt(i)){
                counter++;                
            } else {
                if(counter>20){
                    int multi20 = (counter/20)*20;
                    int mod20 = (counter%20);
                    sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(multi20));
                    if(mod20!=0){
                        sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(mod20) + aux);    
                    } else {
                        sbLinea.append(aux);    
                    }
                } else {
                    sbLinea.append(mapCode.get(counter) + aux);
                }
                counter = 1;
                aux = code.charAt(i);
            }            
        }
        return sbCode.toString();
    }
    private String headDoc(){
        String str = "^XA " +
                        "^FO0,0^GFA,"+ total + ","+ total + "," + widthBytes +", ";
        return str;
    }
    private String footDoc(){
        String str = "^FS"+
                        "^XZ";        
        return str;
    }
    public void setCompressHex(boolean compressHex) {
        this.compressHex = compressHex;
    }
    public void setBlacknessLimitPercentage(int percentage){
        blackLimit = (percentage * 768 / 100);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage orginalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/tmp/logo.jpg"));
        ZPLConveter zp = new ZPLConveter();
        zp.setCompressHex(true);
        zp.setBlacknessLimitPercentage(50);        
        System.out.println(zp.convertfromImg(orginalImage));        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code but the image size is reduced while printing. I guess it's taking 1/3rd to print. I am trying to print an image of width 384 pixel and height 288 pixel of 4/3 ratio

Answer (score 0):

You must add the Zebra SDK for Java [SDK LINK-OS](https://www.zebra.com/la/es/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html). Once the library is imported into the project along with the DLL files, you can use this code:

```
public static String generateZPLCode(String imageFilePath, int newWidth, int newHeight, String x_coordinate, String y_coordinate) throws IOException, ZebraIllegalArgumentException {
    // Load the image
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFilePath));
    image = resize(image, newWidth, newHeight);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    byte[] grfBytes = PngToGrfConverterDesktop.pngToGrf(in);

    String hexData = Hex.encodeHexString(grfBytes);
    int totalBytes = grfBytes.length;
    int bytesPerRow = totalBytes / image.getHeight();

    StringBuilder zplCommand = new StringBuilder();

    zplCommand.append("^F");
    zplCommand.append(x_coordinate);
    zplCommand.append(",");
    zplCommand.append(y_coordinate);
    String comand_image = "^GFA," + totalBytes + "," + totalBytes + "," + bytesPerRow + "," + hexData;
    zplCommand.append(comand_image);

    return zplCommand.toString();
}

private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, img.getType());
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale((double) newWidth / img.getWidth(), (double) newHeight / img.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    resized = scaleOp.filter(img, resized);

    return resized;
}
```

But also make sure to import the library.

```
import com.zebra.sdk.graphics.internal.PngToGrfConverterDesktop;
import com.zebra.sdk.device.ZebraIllegalArgumentException;
```

With this, you will have a result that you can test on this [URL](https://labelary.com/viewer.html) by placing the code between

```
^XA
 {code_return_function}
^XZ
```