# convert jpeg to hexadecimal representation to use in ~DG tag inside the ZPL code

Tags: java, image, hex, bufferedimage, zpl

I am trying to convert and image(jpeg) to the ASCII HEX representation using BufferedImage.
The idea behind this is that i am going to use the HEX representation directly in the ZPL code.

The overall process that i have in mind is as follows:

- Read an img as a BufferedImage
- Read RGB values from the BufferedImage
- convert the read values to 1 or 0 (boolean representation)
- Group the boolean representation into size of 8 (that is one byte) and convert this to a HEX representation.

So far i have been able to achieve the first two steps using the following code.

```
try {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ImageToHex.class.getResourceAsStream("Input.JPG"));

        final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            System.out.println("Pixels : " + pixels);

        final int width = img.getWidth();
        System.out.println("Width : " + width);

        final int height = img.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Height : " + height);

        int[][] result = new int[height][width];

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                result[row][col] = img.getRGB(col, row);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not sure how to proceed with getting a final hex representation of the input image.

Note: There are some zebra specific libraries which convert image to GRF (which is the hex representation) but as of now i don't have any plan to use them.

Appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the ^DG command send image to a zebra printer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156671/how-to-use-the-dg-command-send-image-to-a-zebra-printer-in-java)

Comment: i read your answer earlier as well, the thing is that i need to generate the hex representation without using zebra's api