# create ZPL to print a PNG-image with JAVA

Tags: java, printing, zpl

I want to create a ZPL2-Code, that prints a given PNG-Image. I tried e.g. Labelary Online (http://labelary.com), but I am not able to create the correct image-coding. I converted my PNG to a b/w-image, converted the byte-array to a Hex-String and inserted it like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bwImage, "png", baos);
byte[] bytes =  baos.toByteArray();
System.out.println("^XA^GFA," + bytes.length + "," + bytes.length + "," + bytes.length / 8 + "," + getHexString(bytes) + "^XZ");
```

This works for the Labelary-Online-Preview, but not with real printer. A second point is, that when I insert an image on the Labelary-Website the Hex-String looks a lot different then mine. (It is even no Hex-String).

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156671/how-to-use-the-dg-command-send-image-to-a-zebra-printer-in-java/39976075#39976075

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://labelary.com as an inline image converter. I use the 'Add Image', then select the image data, and save that out to a *.grf file.

If you don't want to use Labelary, you can also use the Zebra Setup Utilities, and convert the image to *.grf, following this article: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7892.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I need the complete zpl-code to send it into another system, and this 3rd-party-system sends it to the printer. That is why i need the whole zpl-code as one string. I just do not know how to convert the image correctly in java.

Comment: I looked into this a bit more, and you could use the Zebra Link OS SDK for Java (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html), which has utilities for converting images to *.grf.

Comment: Yes, but i also need the zpl code around, not only a grf. E.g. the following works in Labelary: `^XA^GFA,121,121,15,89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000050000000500100000000a66acf00000000404944415478da63f80f070ca34c18f31f0342f4f9fffff3b1308f1fe6873177ef848bd6ee4730e7c3998c87e1ccfa9f08057fe14ccbbd48e69e1f8d80e1cb0400fa1d10240f242dc00000000049454e44ae426082^XZ` but not in printer, where it is distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here its another way using Zebra SDK for Java [SDK LINK-OS](https://www.zebra.com/la/es/support-downloads/printer-software/link-os-multiplatform-sdk.html). Once the library is imported into the project along with the DLL files, you can use this code:

```
public static String generateZPLCode(String imageFilePath, int newWidth, int newHeight, String x_coordinate, String y_coordinate) throws IOException, ZebraIllegalArgumentException {
    // Load the image
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFilePath));
    image = resize(image, newWidth, newHeight);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

    byte[] grfBytes = PngToGrfConverterDesktop.pngToGrf(in);

    String hexData = Hex.encodeHexString(grfBytes);
    int totalBytes = grfBytes.length;
    int bytesPerRow = totalBytes / image.getHeight();

    StringBuilder zplCommand = new StringBuilder();

    zplCommand.append("^F");
    zplCommand.append(x_coordinate);
    zplCommand.append(",");
    zplCommand.append(y_coordinate);
    String comand_image = "^GFA," + totalBytes + "," + totalBytes + "," + bytesPerRow + "," + hexData;
    zplCommand.append(comand_image);

    return zplCommand.toString();
}

private static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, img.getType());
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale((double) newWidth / img.getWidth(), (double) newHeight / img.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    resized = scaleOp.filter(img, resized);

    return resized;
}
```

But also make sure to import the library.

```
import com.zebra.sdk.graphics.internal.PngToGrfConverterDesktop;
import com.zebra.sdk.device.ZebraIllegalArgumentException;
```

With this, you will have a result that you can test on this [URL](https://labelary.com/viewer.html) by placing the code between

```
^XA
 {code_return_function}
^XZ
```